# In C++, does a constructor that takes the base class count as a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor, copy-assignment

For example:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    Derived(const Base &rhs)
    {
        // Is this a copy constructor?
    }
    const Derived &operator=(const Base &rhs)
    {
        // Is this a copy assignment operator?
    }
};
```

1. Does the constructor shown count as a copy constructor?
2. Does the assignment operator shown count as a copy assignment operator?

Answer (score 8):

> **Does the constructor shown count as a copy constructor?**

No. It does **not** count as a **copy constructor**.
It is just a **conversion constructor** not a copy constructor.

**C++03 Standard Copying class objects** 
**Para 2:**

> A non-template constructor for class `X` is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments.

---

> **Does the assignment operator shown count as a copy assignment operator?**

No, it doesn't.

**C++03 Standard 12.8 Copying class objects** 
**Para 9:**

> A user-declared copy assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static non-template member function of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`.

---

**[Online Sample:](http://ideone.com/abwVLb)**

```
#include<iostream>
class Base{};
class Derived : public Base
{
   public:
    Derived(){}
    Derived(const Base &rhs)
    {
       std::cout<<"\n In conversion constructor";
    }
    const Derived &operator=(const Base &rhs)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n In operator=";
        return *this;
    }
};

void doSomething(Derived obj)
{
    std::cout<<"\n In doSomething";
}
int main()
{
    Base obj1;
    doSomething(obj1);


    Derived obj2;
    obj2 = obj1;    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
In conversion constructor
In doSomething
In operator=
```

Comment: The quote from the standard for the copy-ctor is incomplete and in this context OP might get the wrong impression. The "full" text is (from C++11): A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Seems about right. And ofcourse, `const` and `volatile` go together as *cv qualifiers*. Wherever you can use one you can use either.

Comment: For the record, since it looks like I answered the previous comment: I never downvoted you, my comment was independent of what others did. A small thing like this is not worth a downvote IMHO.

Comment: @DanielFrey: I know you didn't:). Infact thanks for pointing that out. As I see downvotes should be used to improve answers and I don't mind them as long as they are worthy. I know of someone here with twisted tendencies and when I see that one around same time as I am, I usually get a downvote the moment I answer irrespective of it's correctness. For such idiots who use downvote as a revenge mechanism i have nothing but pity.